# Storing a text file of numbers into an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, filereader

Hi guys i have a text file in the following path C:/Users/Marc/Downloads/vector25 which contains comma-separated values in the following format

-6.08,70.93,-9.35,-86.09,-28.41,27.94,75.15,91.03,-84.21,97.84,
-51.53,77.95,88.37,26.14,-23.58,-18.4,-4.62,46.52,-19.47,17.54,
85.33,52.53,27.97,10.73,-5.82,

How would i read this text file and store those doubles in an array ?

I'm currently thinking of trying a buffered reader but so far the answer eludes me can anyone point me in the right direction ?

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class subvector {

public static void main(String[] args){

    FileReader file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileReader("C:/Users/Marc/Downloads/vector25");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int i=0;
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while(input.hasNext())
        {
           list.add(input.nextDouble());
           i++;
        }
        input.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   for(double k:list){
       System.out.println(k);

   }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Do you have a problem? An error?

Answer (score 3):

`Scanner.nextDouble()` uses whitespace as the delimiter by default. Your input has commas as delimiter. You should use `input.useDelimiter(",")` to set commas as the delimiter before calling `input.hasNext()`. Then it should work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a delimeter

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
input.useDelimeter(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code snippet will not for the specified data i.e. -6.08,70.93,-9.35,-86.09,-28.41,27.94,75.15,91.03,-84.21,97.84, -51.53,77.95,88.37,26.14,-23.58,-18.4,-4.62,46.52,-19.47,17.54, 85.33,52.53,27.97,10.73,-5.82,

But your program will work fine these type of data :

```
19.60
63.0
635.00
896.63
47.25
```

I have modified your program and tested with your data also. It's working as expected.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileReader file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileReader("D:\\log4j\\vector25.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int i=0;
    Double d= null;
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(file);
        String s=null;
        while((s=input.readLine())!=null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s,",");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            try {
                d = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            list.add(i, d);
        }
    }
    input.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
for(double k:list) {
    System.out.println(k);
}
}
```

Please review it and let me know if you update anything.

This is my first POST on stackoverflow.

Thanks, Prasad